# checking a checkbox based on other checkboxes being checked in access

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I have a form in access 2010 with a checkbox field named DR Process, then I have 25 other checkbox fields that if checked I want the DR Process checkbox to automatically be checked. Also if one of the 25 field is checked then unchecked it should uncheck the DR Process checkbox. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour that you are describing for your controls sounds similar to that of having multiple checkboxes accompanied by a *Select All* checkbox to simultaneously enable or disable all checkboxes in the set:

[image: Select All]

To achieve this, I believe you will need to use some VBA code in the various `After Update` event handlers for your controls.

In the following example, I am assuming that you have a set of checkboxes called `chk1`, `chk2`, and `chk3` and a single *Select All* checkbox called `chkA` (however, this could be expanded to any number of checkboxes by simply increasing the upper limit of the `For` loops).

You could then achieve the desired behaviour using the following two functions:

**A function to toggle all option checkboxes to a given value:**

```
Function ToggleAll(v As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        Controls("chk" & i).Value = v
    Next i
End Function
```

---

**A function to test whether or not all option checkboxes are enabled and enable or disable the *Select All* checkbox accordingly:**

```
Function AllEnabled()
    Dim i As Integer, v As Integer: v = -1
    For i = 1 To 3
        v = v * Abs(Controls("chk" & i).Value)
    Next i
    chkA.Value = v
End Function
```

---

Then, you simply need to evaluate the above functions from within the `After Update` event handlers for your controls:

```
Private Sub chk1_AfterUpdate()
    AllEnabled
End Sub

Private Sub chk2_AfterUpdate()
    AllEnabled
End Sub

Private Sub chk3_AfterUpdate()
    AllEnabled
End Sub

Private Sub chkA_AfterUpdate()
    ToggleAll chkA
End Sub
```

Here, every time the value of the individual option checkboxes is altered, the `AllEnabled` function checks whether all option checkboxes are enabled and sets the value of the *Select All* checkbox accordingly.

When the value of the *Select All* checkbox (`chkA`) is modified, the `ToggleAll` function is evaluated, simultaneously enabling or disabling the setting of all option checkboxes on the form.